# How do I make Java recognize the "Enter" key?

Tags: java

so I'm trying to develop a code that asks the user for a password, and, in the end, to tell the user how many attempts he/she did before correctly guessing the password. Until that point, everything seems to be working just fine. I want to add the following features:

- If the user presses "Enter", the program asks the password again but the count goes back to 0.
- While the user doesn't get the password right, the program will display the following message: "incorrect password".

This is my current code:

```
public class pwtry {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String psswd = "passw0rd";
        int nA = 0;
        String attempt = "";
        do {
            attempt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter password: ");
            nA ++;
        }
        
        while(!attempt.equals(psswd));
        
        
        String result = "You got the password in " + nA + " attempts.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, 
                result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well pressing enter is equivalent to entering nothing right? So `if (attempt.equals(""))` or `if (attempt.isEmpty())`

Comment: @Michael, will that end the current cycle and being a new one?